# STR_TO_DATE issue with 24 hr timestamp

Tags: mysql

Friends,

I'm struggling with something that appears to be an easy thing. I have a lengthy date/time string that I want to convert, but for some reason the first digit in hour gets replaced with a '0' characters.

```
STR_TO_DATE('Tue Aug 29 22:44:25 2017', '%W %M %D %H:%i:%s %Y')
```

Result

```
2017-08-29 02:44:25
```

Doesn't matter what time I use, for instance **11:11** becomes **01:11**. I thought %H would handle this but apparently not this time.

All suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As usual the answer comes to you after you've posted the question. My mistake was to not consider the abbrevated format of the date. Changing to this solved it.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Tue Aug 29 22:44:25 2017', '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Y')
```